# Link doesn't work underneath an image link (with a line break in between)

Tags: html, css

This is quite strange to me... I have a small image that's a link and a text link underneath that. If I separate them with a `<br/>`, the text shows up formatted like a link but you cannot click it. If I use `<p> </p>` instead, the link works fine... I just don't want that much space in between them. I've closed both link tags so that's not the issue, and I've tested it in both Firefox and Chrome and both gave me the same issue.

Code portion:

```
    <div id="content">
    <br/><a href="#newtitles">
<img src="images/sterling.png" style="border: 1.5px; border-style:solid;"/></a>
    <br/>
    <a href="#newtitles">Fall 2011 Catalog</a><div style="position: relative;left:155px;bottom:20px;"><img src="images/new.png"/></div><hr/><br/>
</div>
```

I've determined that this is being caused by the neighboring div:

```
<div style="position: relative;left:155px;bottom:20px;"><img src="images/new.png"/></div>
```

When I take it out, the link works again for some reason.

Comment: I feel that this is probably a CSS issue.  Can you post your CSS for this example?

Comment: it works as expected for me
http://jsfiddle.net/eatchocolate/kUMvt/

Comment: Edited: it's the div... still not sure why though

Comment: Do you have a live link where we can see it in action? As @mrborna said, it works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

You could always adjust the `line-height` property for the `<p>` so that there is the same amount of space as there would be with a `<br />`.

Answer (score 0):

You can give the `<p>` an id, and then adjust its `line-height`, `padding`, `margin`, etc properties to remove some white-space.

This does not seem to be an html issue, but rather one with the layout. Can you post the relevant css? or even better, make a [fiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net/)